# Can't edit NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nstextview

I cerated an NSTextView using Interface Build, I also connected it's delegate to File's Owner.

For some reason when I run the application I can't edit the NSTextView text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: this question is a little confusing... do you want the user to be able to edit text or do you want to modify text in code?

Comment: I want the user to be able to edit the text
Thanks

Comment: Have you implemented any text field delegate methods? What do they do? You could be preventing editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set it as editable in interface builder or in code:

```
- (void)setEditable:(BOOL)flag
```

Comment: Yes...
The NSTextView is part of an NSViewController which is being display via NSPopover